# Relocate views in the navigationcontroller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, subviews

Is it possible to relocate a uiview that I've added as a subview of a viewcontroller? This is my problem:

navigationcontroller stack -> viewcontroller -> rectangle view

When I change the device orientation I want to relocate the rectangle view. How can I access that rectangle subview?

Thanks for your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag the view, which is probably what you want (so you can get it back later with viewWithTag) or run through subviews array looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

use IB to set size&position and autoresizing properly

then u can do that